# Can I get Azure Blob storage to send me a blob resized?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an MVC application which allows users to sell items and upload images associated with each item. I am using Azure Blob storage to store the images. Once the image is stored in Azure, the MVC backend might retrieve it and resize it (usually shrink it) before sending it to the client, depending on requirements. Is there anyway I can request a file from Azure and have Azure resize it for me? This would save on the expense of sending a large image file to my MVC controller, which I then resize and stream to the client. Of course, I know I could save multiple copies of each image in Azure, each with the size I might need.

Comment: You can use a webjob with a blob trigger to resize the image and put resized versions in another blob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Azure Blob storage is not designed process the content of your files in any way.

Simple binary upload and download.